# Flutter Riverpod - using read() inside build method

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Suppose I want to initialize a text field by using the `initialValue:` property on a `TextFormField`, and I need my initial value to come from a provider. I read on the [docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers) that calling `read()` from inside the build method is considered bad practice, but calling from handlers is fine (like `onPressed`). So I'm wondering if its fine to call read from the `initialValue` property like shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you should use `useProvider` if you are using hooks, or a `ConsumerWidget` / `Consumer` if you are not.

The difference being, the `initialValue` field is a part of the build method, and like you said, `onPressed` is a handler, outside of the build method.

A core aspect of providers is optimizing rebuilds as provided values change. Using `context.read` in the build method is nullifying this benefit as you aren't listening to the provided value.

Using `context.read` is highly recommended in anonymous functions (`onChanged`, `onPressed`, `onTap`, etc.) because those functions are retrieving the provided value *at the time the function is executed.* This means the function will always execute with the current value of that provider, without having to listen to the provider. The other methods for reading providers use a listener which is more expensive and unnecessary in the case of anonymous functions.

In your example, you wanted to set `initialValue` of a `TextFormField`. The following is how you could use [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) and [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) to accomplish that.

```dart
class HooksExample extends HookWidget {
  const HooksExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: useProvider(loginStateProv).email,
    );
  }
}
```

And for readers who prefer to not use hooks:

```dart
class ConsumerWidgetExample extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ConsumerWidgetExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: watch(loginStateProv).email,
    );
  }
}
```

Or:

```dart
class ConsumerExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConsumerExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, child) {
        return TextFormField(
          initialValue: watch(loginStateProv).email,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The primary difference being that `Consumer` will only rebuild its children because only they are relying on provided data.

Comment: Thanks, kind of suspected that. I appreciate the info, so if I'm getting this right, I'm supposed to do something like `initialValue: useProvider(someProvider.select((value) => value.someField)),` ?

Comment: assuming I want to display `someField`. 

Also, does `onChanged` fall into the same category as `onPressed`, is using `read()` safe in an `onChanged` on a `TextFormField`?

Comment: Addressed your questions by expanding my answer. It seems you have deleted your account, but hope it can still help you and future readers.

Comment: Thanks @alex-hartford, glad I found this - helped me a lot!

Comment: Sir , What's difference between read & watch ?

Comment: @OmarEssam `read`, like its name, reads the value at the time you call `read`. `watch` will read the value at the time you call `watch`, but continue to watch for updates to the provided value, and update / rebuild when those updates occur.