# Flutter Riverpod context.read vs Provider in the build method

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

In the Riverpod [documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading) it says:

> That's where `context.read(myProvider)` is a solution.
>
> Using it, we could refactor our previous code to:
>
> ```dart
> @override 
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
>   return RaisedButton(
>     onPressed: () => context.read(counterProvider).state++,
>     child: Text('increment'),
>   ); 
> }
> ```
>
> By doing so, clicking on our button still increments the counter. But we are no-longer listening to
> the provider, which avoids unnecessary rebuilds.

But then it says:

> caution
>
> Avoid calling `context.read` inside the `build` method of a Widget. If you
> want to optimize rebuilds, extract the value listened in a Provider
> instead.

This is a little confusing to me. First the documentation gives an example of using `context.read` inside the `build` method and then it gives a warning to avoid it. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Riverpod - using read() inside build method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64253162/flutter-riverpod-using-read-inside-build-method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `build` method can be called multiple times during layout. Thus you should avoid doing any extra work inside it (like calling a method on your model).

However, the `onPressed` callback of the `RaisedButton` doesn't actually get called when `build` is called. `onPressed` is only called when the user presses the button. Only then will Riverpod read your provider and call the method on the model. So the warning in the documentation doesn't apply in that situation.

Comment: Do you know what an example of `extract the value listened in a Provider instead` would look like?

As to me it seems like in the docs they always read providers inside the build method if reading from inside a widget. I fail to see how using `watch` inside the build method is a better solution. Could it mean to use ProviderContainer().read() from within the widget, but outside of the build method?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins, That's a good question. I'm a little unclear on that myself, too.